# Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback on session timeout?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, callback, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I have implemented a callback method using ASP.Net AJAX and want to redirect to when this callback happen to another page. Since redirect is not possible when requesting from a callback . I get the error `"Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback"`.

How do i make a call back redirect in general for any callback event that gets fired ?? 
That is for example : I have a RadComboBox which implements callbacks to server on every letter typed in the radcombobox. 
Say now while requesting for an item for the RadComboBox there is a session timeout and the application requires to be redirected to another page . How do i go about this ?

when in a callback no scripts can be executed that is scripts like `ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(this.gettype(),"script","Do javascript redirect to session timeout page ?",true);`

Only other way i see to get around this to probably add a check in my MasterPage Load method which checks if a session is timed out and add to HttpCookie then on the MasterPage html add a javascript method which has a timeout interval which checks for a value in the cookie so that it could be redirected to another page ? ! . Now, this method would require to be run all the time could probably result in some performace related issues ??

Is there any other way i could achive redirection while an request is from a callback ?
I have tried the Response.RedirectLocation to but seems to have no effect ?

Comment: same here, any solutions?

Comment: Yes, at the control level display a message when there is a timeout stating that the session timed out. And in the page you are causing a redirect put a check right before the redirect Page.IsCallBack then skip

Answer (score 1):

The web project i work on implements Redirection on session timeout
The issue i was facing was during a callback if a session timed out it used to result in this error.

My implementation for checking session time out is have a session variable set during login and during each page load check for this session value to be null and then redirect to login since time out timeout.
So now as a solution i display a message in the control which causes a callback that "**Session timed out** " and in my master page which checks for session time out added code  so that it could redirect to the login page was preceeded with a check .

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsCallback)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx",true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Server.Transfer` method and see if that woks.

Other option is to send a True/False back to the client and have javascript method that will accept this and make redirection.

Here is an example how to invoke server side method using jQuery and accept it’s results.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_retrieve_data_from_pagemethod.ashx